# Access ListBox.SelectedItems from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have `ListBox` called lstProductGroups.

On a simple Windows Form, a method called `GetGroups` gives me string groups selected by the user like `Cars, Bikes` etc.

```
public List<string> GetGroups()
{
    List<string> prodGroups = (from object item in lstProductGroups.SelectedItems select item.ToString()).ToList();

    return prodGroups;
}
```

But if I try to access same method from another thread I get all items in my list called `System.Data.DataRowView`.

I even tried it in a `foreach` loop with `BeginInvoke`, but the `item.ToString()` always returns `System.Data.DataRowView`.

I am new to Winforms with threading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using to facilitate threading; `BackgroundWorker`, `Thread`, `Task`?

Comment: Did you try to call GetGroups() method from the other thread with Invoke()? It should return the right list.

Comment: Third party API's event that I am subscribed to. I do not know their internal implementation. But any UI update code from the event method raised `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Comment: @Adriano tried it. Still same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare a delegate:

```
delegate List<string> GetItemsDlg();
```

Change your method like this:

```
List<string> GetGroups() {
    if (lstProductGroups.InvokeRequired) {
        var dlg = new GetItemsDlg(GetGroups);
        return lstProductGroups.Invoke(dlg) as List<string>;
    }
    List<string> prodGroups = (from object item in lstProductGroups.SelectedItems select item.ToString()).ToList();

    return prodGroups;

}
```

Call your method:

```
List<string> items = GetGroups();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about invoke:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                               {
                                 ...
                               }
```